# How to force refresh each page in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I can't seem to figure out how to turn of the cache successfully in my rails app. The website I made is http://www.liftlineclothing.com and upon using the navbar to click to the clothing page, the clothes do no appear unless you refresh the page once you are on it. As well, when navigating back to the homepage, the Javascript to get the text to fly in does not appear unless you refresh the page as well.

I am pretty sure this is a cache problem but if any one has some ideas, I would really appreciate it. I have gone in the config file and changed the rails cache to false.

UPDATE

here is the javascript

```
var pausebetweenmsg=10 //customize pause in miliseconds between each message showing up  
(3000=3 seconds)
var glidespeed=50 //customize glide speed in pixels per frame.

var curobjindex=0

function actualstyle(el, cssproperty){
if (el.currentStyle)
return el.currentStyle[cssproperty]
else if (window.getComputedStyle){
var elstyle=window.getComputedStyle(el, "")
return elstyle.getPropertyValue(cssproperty)
 }
}

function collectElementbyClass(){
var classname="glidetext"
glidearray=new Array()
var inc=0
var alltags=document.all? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName("*")
for (i=0; i<alltags.length; i++){
if (alltags[i].className==classname)
glidearray[inc++]=alltags[i]
}
if (glidearray.length>0)
onebyoneglide()
}

function onebyoneglide(){
if (curobjindex<glidearray.length)
glidetimer=setInterval("glideroutine()",50)
}

function glideroutine(){
if (parseInt(actualstyle(glidearray[curobjindex], "left"))<0)
glidearray[curobjindex].style.left=parseInt(actualstyle(glidearray[curobjindex], "left"))+50+"px"
else{
glidearray[curobjindex].style.left=0
curobjindex++
clearInterval(glidetimer)
setTimeout("onebyoneglide()", pausebetweenmsg)
}
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", collectElementbyClass, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", collectElementbyClass)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=collectElementbyClass
```

This send the text flying onto the page from the homepage that is not working when navigated to from another page. You have to refresh the home page as well.

As for the clothing javascript, that is handle by ecwid. I will update once I can locate the specific javascript that is being used by them.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a caching issue to me, it looks like Turbolinks is messing up your loading of content. Either read up on disabling/working around Turbolinks or try https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks if it fits your needs. With Chrome Inspector open, you can see that clicking your nav links is not actually reloading your page, so your `$(document).ready` events don't actually fire past the first page.

Additionally, ff I follow the link to your page, refresh, and then click any nav link, your page starts generating 1 JS error per second.

```
Uncaught com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'userAgent' of null 0.js:3836
1398638731162: EcwidEntryPoint: uncaught exception com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException:
(TypeError) : Cannot read property 'userAgent' of null
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will check up on that and see if it works for me.

Comment: I installed the jquery-turbolinks but still having the same issue. I turned off turbo links setting the data-turbolinks to false. I am still having the same issue about the navbar not reloading the page. I  appologize if I am missing something here but if there is any further info you might have please let me know.

Comment: What does the code look like that is supposed to make the content load into the page and what is the action that's supposed to make it happen? If you want to totally rule out turbolinks, you can disable the gem, run `bundle install`, and then modify your javascript_include_tag in `application.html.erb` to just say `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`.

Comment: I update my post to include what you asked. Thank you again for helping. I am not quite sure what you mean by the action other than the navbar navigating to the page triggering the javascript to show.

Comment: It's still hard to say where it's breaking down, but it seems clear that the code is not hooking into page load events the way you want it to, so that's what you need to focus on. It's possible that another error in your code is preventing it from making it there, so you might want to try to fix the `Uncaught com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'userAgent' of null` errors that run constantly when the page loads. Also, why are you trying to load the content with JS? Why not use a Rails template and load in the view like it's supposed to?